# RestRequestAsyncHandle.Abort() won't trigger CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested

Tags: c#, asynchronous, restsharp, nancy

I have two C# app running simultaneously. One is a C# console app that sends REST calls to the other and the other is running a Nancy self hosted rest server.

Here's a really basic view of some of the code of both parts.

RestsharpClient:

```
public async void PostAsyncWhile()
{
    IRestClient RestsharpClient = new RestClient("http://localhost:50001");

    var request = new RestRequest($"/nancyserver/whileasync", Method.POST);

    var asyncHandle = RestsharpClient.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ToString());
    });

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    asyncHandle.Abort();//PROBLEM
}
```

NancyRestServer:

```
public class RestModule : NancyModule
{
    public RestModule() : base("/nancyserver")
    {
        Post("/whileasync", async (args, ctx) => await WhileAsync(args, ctx));
    }

    private async Task<bool> WhileAsync(dynamic args, CancellationToken ctx)
    {
        do
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            if (ctx.IsCancellationRequested)//PROBLEM
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true);

        return true;
    }
}
```

The client sends a command to start a while loop on the server, waits for 1sec and aborts the async call.

The problem I'm having is that the `asyncHandle.Abort();` doesn't seem to trigger the `ctx.IsCancellationRequested` on the server's side.

**How am I supposed to cancel/abort an async call on a nancy host server using a restsharp client?**

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of parts that go into cancelling a web request.

First, the client must support cancellation and use that cancellation to clamp the connection closed. So the first thing to do is to monitor the network packets (e.g., using Wireshark) and make sure RestSharp is sending a RST (reset), and *not* just closing its side of the connection. An RST is a signal to the other side that you want to cancel the request. Closing the connection is a signal to the other side that you're done sending data but are still willing to receive a response.

Next, the server must support detecting cancellation. Not all servers do. For quite a while, ASP.NET (pre-Core) did *not* properly support client-initiated request cancellation. There was some kind of race condition where it wouldn't cancel properly (don't remember the details), so they disabled that cancellation path. This has all been sorted out in ASP.NET Core, but AFAIK, it was never fixed in ASP.NET Legacy Edition.

If RestSharp is not sending an RST, then open an issue with that team. If Nancy is not responding to the RST, then open an issue with that team. If it's an ASP.NET issue, the Nancy team should know that (and respond informing you they can't fix it), in which case you're out of luck. :/

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Knowing this information, I'll surely try to wireshark my way out! :P If nothing works, I'll just rethink the way I'm doing this operation and come up with another idea.

Comment: Cancelling web requests is more of a "best effort" kind of thing. If you *require* cancellation for business reasons, then I would definitely structure the cancellation as a separate request.